# question on GWT and dockpanel , sizing and resizing

Tags: java, web-applications, gwt

question on dock panels within gwt

So i want the dockpanel to take up the whole size of the browser window

```
        dockPanel.setSize("100%", "100%");
```

if this correct

Next Question, 
i am going to add a north panel , that will be 100px high and take up the whole width of the browser

```
    topPanel.setSize("100%", "100px");
    dockPanel.add(topPanel, DockPanel.NORTH);
```

is this correct, 
then i want to add a west panel that is 200px wide and the whole length of the browser up to just under the north panel
    westSideStackPanel.setSize("200px","100%")
    mainPanel.add(westSideStackPanel,DockPanel.WEST);

i have created all this but when i look at my dockpanel there is a big gap between the west panel and the north panel the whole way accross the screen. why would this be?

The north panel stays at 100px, and then there is a gap of about 100px high the whole width of the screen.

[image]

Comment: Can you include a screenshot of what you're seeing vs. what you'd like to see? It's kind of difficult to understand what's going on by your description.

Comment: updated and placed the screen shot in, as you can see , from the stackpanel to the orange north part, is a gap

Answer (score 3):

Try using [RootLayoutPanel](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/RootLayoutPanel.html) as the base panel (this resizes to the browser window) then use a DockLayoutPanel (v similar to a DockPanel).
This approach is documented [here](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiPanels.html#LayoutPanels).

```
public void onModuleLoad() {
    RootLayoutPanel rp = RootLayoutPanel.get();
    DockLayoutPanel dp = new DockLayoutPanel(Unit.PX);
    rp.add(dp);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Yes, it is mandatory that you use RootLayoutPanel. Unfortunately, it's not his problem here, since using RootPanel would cause everything to be far from what he want. It had happened to me once (forgetting the RootLayoutPanel) and all my widget were glued to the top.

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced some kind of similar problem with DockLayoutPanel in the past and my solution for you would be : switch to LayoutPanel. LayoutPanel can do everything a DockLayoutPanel can do but gives you way more flexibility. In the end, you'll only win out of using LayoutPanel.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
dockPanel.setCellHeight(topPanel, "100px");
dockPanel.setCellHeight(westSideStackPanel, "100%");
```

I don't have much experience with the old DockPanel, but I assume, this could work, because it should set the height of the cells - as opposed to the height of the widgets inside the cells.

In any case, it's probably a good idea to use Firebug to find out exactly, where the gap comes from!